# Gradle custom task specify inputs

Tags: gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am creating a plugin for our releasing methods. One of the tasks I need should collect the distZip output of each subprojects this task depends on and packs them into one zip file with some static files.

Here is my plugin (all other tasks and extension removed for simplicity):

```
open class SemanticVersionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.create("release", ReleaseTask::class.java) {
            group = "releasing"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my task:

```
open class ReleaseTask : Zip() {

    // This fuction copies the content of the distZip output into this task    
    private fun addProjectResultToRelease(zip: Zip, projectPath: String) {
        logger.quiet("   Adding $projectPath")
        with(zip) {
            val distTaskName = "$projectPath:distZip"
            val task = project.tasks.findByPath(distTaskName) ?: throw GradleException("Task not found: $distTaskName")
            task.outputs.files.filter { it.extension == "zip" }.forEach {
                val srcZip = project.zipTree(it)
                //includeEmptyDirs = false
                from(srcZip) {
                    eachFile {
                        this.path = (this.path.replaceBefore(delimiter = "/", replacement = ""))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Some default value overrides
    init {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        destinationDir = File("_release")
        baseName = project.name
    }


    @Suppress("unused")
    @TaskAction
    fun action() {
        val ext = project.extensions["semanticVersion"] as SemanticVersionExtension

        println(dependsOn.joinToString { it.toString() })

        // Iterating through dependencies
        dependsOn.forEach {
            it as String
            println("DEP: $it")
            addProjectResultToRelease(this, it.substringBeforeLast(":"))
        }

        from(project.file("version.txt"))

        super.copy()
    }
}
```

In the build script where I use it:

```
tasks.withType<ReleaseTask> {
    dependsOn(":core:distZip")
}
```

First question: is the `init` block the right place to set up or override defaults?

When I run this task, I got "NO-SOURCE" message:

```
> ...
> Task :core:distZip UP-TO-DATE
> Task :release NO-SOURCE
```

How can I specify that the outputs of the corresponding distZips are the inputs of this task?

Answer (score 0):

After a few dozens of different approaches, I've found a solution. I wasn't far from the correct implementation with overriding the `dependsOn` function.

First of all, I switched to version 5.4. It made some of the properties  of ZipTask deprecated, but otherwise the upgrade was straightforward.

```
open class ReleaseTask : Zip() {

    // This function zips out the zip files and removes the root directory    
    private fun addProjectResultToRelease(task: Task) {
        logger.quiet("   Adding ${task.path}")
        task.outputs.files.apply { println(this) }.filter { it.extension == "zip" }.forEach {
            val srcZip = project.zipTree(it)
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            from(srcZip) {
                eachFile {
                    this.path = (this.path.replaceBefore(delimiter = "/", replacement = ""))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This overrides calls the unzip function for each dependancy
    override fun dependsOn(vararg paths: Any?): Task {
        super.dependsOn(*paths)

        paths.forEach {
            val t = project.tasks.getByPath(it.toString())
            addProjectResultToRelease(t)
        }

        return this
    }

    // Some refactor was needed for upgrade
    init {
        println("Init")
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        from(project.file("version.txt"))
        destinationDirectory.set(project.file("_release"))
        archiveBaseName.set(project.name)
    }

    // At the moment this function override is needless, but here will come some other 
    // activities later
    override fun copy() {
        val ext = project.extensions["semanticVersion"] as SemanticVersionExtension

        println(archiveFile.get())

        super.copy()
    }
}
```

I still not completely content with settings in `init` block. There may be a lifecycle function to override instead, but I missed it.